# Start Activity for result not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm using start Activity result for starting a  new activity to select a image from gallery and it will return a image path to my main activity to , so that it will insert image in my main activity,

here is my code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Image.class);
    intent.putExtra(UUID, image.getUuid().toString());
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    case PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        String uuidStr = data.getStringExtra(UUID);
        log.v("image url",uuiStr);            
        break;
    }
}
```

but i'm getting following crashes

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, 
result=-1,data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity       
{com.write.example/com.write.example.MainWriterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: plz find in logs that in MainWriterActivity on which line does NPE occurs

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: Better you put log for result code and request code before switch statement.The u can find what happen

Answer (score 1):

The intent is wrong, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Start Activity

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Take Result

```
 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null)
     {
       Uri _uri = data.getData();
       //User had pick an image.
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] {     
       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       //Link to the image
       final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);

       cursor.close();
     }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

}