# Picking photos from SD-Card which where not taken by the device camera

Tags: android

i tried to pick photos from my sd card using this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_pick_photo)), Globals.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_PHOTO);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_PHOTO) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            this.onPhotoPicked(Helper.getAbsoluteImagePath(this, data.getData()));
        }
    }
}

private void onPhotoPicked(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePicked = true;
    this.imageTaken = false;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.imagePath, options);
    this.imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

This works fine for all photos i pick which where taken by the device camera.
If i want to choose photos from other places thx to this method:

```
public static String getAbsoluteImagePath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But somehow this does not work for photos that i pick from sd card which where
not taken by the device camera like downloads, dropbox or facebook photos.
If i try to `cursor.getString(columnIndex)` is always null.

So how can i pick photos which where not taken by the camera?

Comment: problem in pic photo from gallery

Comment: have u not pass any String in This Methed this.onPhotoTaken();

Comment: no because i dont need. onPhotoTaken is working fine. onPhotoPicked() is the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728782/start-activity-for-result-not-working/26728850#26728850

Comment: Please use This code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728782/start-activity-for-result-not-working/26728850#26728850

Comment: Check my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882479/trying-to-get-an-image-from-gallery-or-camera-in-android/25882760#25882760

Comment: I edited my answer because with the solution from the link you sent me i get nullpointerexceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add this permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: do not need this permission when we pic photo from gallery

Comment: Yes i have added those permissions.